# Replace rows, 1 by 1 with three different conditions, into a list with same order as input

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working on a script, for grading students. I've made a function, which rounds/scales the grades to the closest value on a list:

```
def roundGrade(mean_grade):
    #grouped scale
    grade_groups = [-3,0,2,4,7,10,12]
    #round grade/scale to nearest number in grade_groups
    gradesRounded = [(abs(grade-mean_grade),grade)for grade in grade_groups]
    #sort rounded values
    gradesRounded.sort()
    return gradesRounded[0][1]
```

Then I need to compute the final grade for the students based on three conditions and gather them in an array. I've come up with this code, but it wont compute, can you guys help me in the right direction? It's fair to mention that Im fairly new to programming and still struggling to learn the language and the syntax.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from roundGrade1 import roundGrade
grades = pd.read_csv('Karakterer.csv')

def computeFinalGrades(grades):
    #making a numpy array from df
    arr=grades.values
    #sortinig and deleting the first two columns
    grades=np.sort(np.delete(arr,(0,1),axis=1))
    #setting up a list for the final grades
    gradesFinal=[]
    for i in range(len(grades)):
        #if -3 is in a row, the final grade should be = -3
        if -3 in grades:

            gradesFinal[i]= -3
        #if there is 2 or more grades in a row, execute the procedure below
        elif len(grades)>=2:
            meangrade=np.delete(grades,0,axis=1)

            finalgrade = np.mean(meangrade)
            gradesFinal[i] = roundGrade(finalgrade)

        # if there is only one value in the row, return that as the final grade 
        elif len(grades)==1:
            gradesFinal[i] = grades


    return gradesFinal
```

This is could be an example of the df:

```
  StudentID               Name  Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3 
0   s123456   Michael Andersen            7            5             4
1   s123789   Bettina Petersen           12            3            10
2   s123468     Thomas Nielsen           -3            7             2
```

Comment: `grades` is a list of lists `[][]`.  So to get a row from grades, you do `grades[i]`.  For example, `-3 in grades` will always be false because grades is a list of lists, not a list of numbers.  However, grades[i] is a list of numbers.

Comment: Allright, i see.. but how do i make  ```grades``` into a list of numbers instead of a list of lists?

Comment: You replace all occurrences of `grades` with `grades[i]` in your `for` loop.  `if -3 in grades[i]` etc. etc.

Comment: Wonderful, that works. While I have you here, I have another question. How do i replace the grades from my df with the list i just created? This could a example of the df: (messed up in the comments so i put in the question above)

Then i need a new column where it says "Final Grade" with the data from the new list created

Comment: If are already starting with a dataframe, you could simply use a UDF to do the processing and adding the additional column....Won't even need to use numpy. Assuming pandas dataframe, look into apply. Would be faster than converting to numpy. I could post a full code up if you need it.

Comment: Hi Jason, i had a hard time processing within pd, that's why i went into something a little more familiar, numpy. But i would love to see your solution, it might be easier to work with when i start on my mainscript